# How to make Vertical Bar Graph like this wtih canvas

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umIMY.jpg)

I'm Starting to learning HTML but i dont know how to make this by Canvas

Answer (score 1):

Heres a sample of Bar Graph for you.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("daylight").getContext("2d");

var data = {
  
  labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",],
  datasets: [{
    label: "This is where your label",
    backgroundColor: "#f5c74e",
    borderWidth: "2",
    borderColor: "darkgray",
    data: [1, 3, 6, 2, 8, 5,]
    
  }]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
  plugins: {
   title: {
    display: 'true',
     text: 'VERTICAL BAR GRAPH',
     alignment:'left',
     display:'vertical',
      barValueSpacing: '1',
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
        }
        
      }],

       }
       }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="daylight" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
how to use this script??

Comment: thats the source of the chart js.

Comment: thats the source code of the chart js, you have to put that  to make it work. put that source code on top of your script like this <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>then put this at the bottom of it<script> the code above close</script>

Comment: im using editplust rn so i cant use that code?

Comment: that should work if you download the entire source code.